# need data before constructor angular (no resolver)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dialog service. I create the dialog component using viewContainerRef and ComponentFactory.
Now, this component is made. and I set a default value to a property in this component.

```
 this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
 this.componentRef.instance.data = configData;
```

This component inherits from a base class (with super).

There's a virtual method that calls in my component (call from the base class).

I want that default value but the instance is not filled yet.

Comment: didn't get what you want to achieve

Comment: @AakashGarg  Can't we give that data when creating the component? Not after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its by default that you can't access input properties in constructor. if you still want to do it you can use injector for that.

constructor(injector: Injector){};

```
const injector = Injector.create({
   providers: [{provide: 'data', useValue: this.configData}],
   parent: this.injector
})

this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory, {injector});
```

and in your component then you can use it like :-

```
constructor(@Inject('data') data: any){
    // source code;
}
```

Comment: It was a good solution. I had the data in the constructor and passed it to the base class. And there I passed the method that was written. Thank you so much

Comment: @AbolfazlAlmas can you please upvote this answer if it helped and mark it as answer?

Comment: Yes, of course, but I can not upvote because I do not have at least 15 reputations . +_+